# Javascript to create an app that automatically plays Youtube videos

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'm trying to make an app that automatically plays a list of Youtube videos. You can see what I have so far: http://jaminweb.com/YoutubePlaylist.html.

I've reached a dead end because I can't figure out the logistics of getting an embedded video to play automatically and then have some sort of even listener to see when it ends.

What I have so far is this:

```
        this.playAll = function()
        {
            var vidtexts = document.getElementsByClassName('vidtxt');
            var i = 0, j = vidtexts.length;
            while (i < j)
            {
               var thisid = vidtexts[i].value;
               if (thisid.length != 0)
               {
                  var thisurl= this.id2url(vidtexts[i].value);
                  document.getElementById("ytframe").src = thisurl; 
                  // want that video to play all the way through
               }
               ++i;
            }
        }
```

Which simply goes through all the video IDs the user has provided and changes the source of the `iframe` element to the corresponding video. Any suggestions for what I can do? Or is this impossible? (Nothing is impossible for Stack Overflow haha)

Comment: can't you set autoplay to true in url?

Comment: Take a look at youtube's player API and especially the functions ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en#Functions ) and the events ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en#Events ). You'll need an event to know when the video is ready or ended and you'll need functions to play a video.